# Intermittent URLFetch error between modules on Google App Engine

Tags: php, google-app-engine, urlfetch

I have a paid App Engine Application.

It has 2 modules. The default is in PHP and there is a 'data' module, written in Python.

The data module is for interacting with Datastore using the Python ndb library.

I call the 'data' module from my PHP module - around 20 times per minute.

Most of the time, all is well and data flows into Datastore via my Python endpoint.

From time to time (once every 10 minutes or so) the call fails, resulting in data loss, with this message (sensitive text replaced with 'xxx'):

```
PHP Warning:  file_get_contents(http://data.xxx.appspot.com/create/http-state): failed to open stream: Fetch error in xxx.php on line 29
```

Here is line 29 of the offending file:

```
return file_get_contents($str_endpoint, FALSE, $obj_context);
```

At these failure points, there is no entry in the log for the target module.

Can anyone shed some light on this?

Thanks

--

Code added:

```
   public static function httpPostArray($str_endpoint, $arr_data)
   {
      $arr_opts = [
         'http' => [
            'method' => 'POST',
            'header' => 'Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
            'content' => http_build_query($arr_data)
         ]
      ];
      $obj_context = stream_context_create($arr_opts);
      return file_get_contents($str_endpoint, FALSE, $obj_context);
   }
```

Comment: what context options are you supplying for the call? in particular the timeout value. a failure should be rare, but I guess it's not impossible - you should try and add some retry logic to the call if possible.

Comment: Here's the function call, with all current parameters

Comment: @StuartLangley Function added to the main thread above.  Not specifically adding any timeout data - I can do so.  Also, the retry logic had crossed my mind, but the level of failure seems untoward?

Comment: The failure rate does seem high but the odd failure is possible so you should retry if possible. You could put it into a task queue if the process can be done asynchronously to the users request and you get the retry for free.

Comment: I guess what I would like to understand is where the failure is coming from.  I do not think it is my PHP, as it's coming from the re-implemented file_get_contents() method.  I also do not think it is coming from the Python - as there is no hint of the request even making it to that module.  As such, it looks like the failure is coming from the Google URLFetch proxy layer. Could this be the case?

Comment: quite possibly but without knowing the app_id it's hard to put a finger on it.

Comment: @StuartLangley I'll drop you a line on Hangouts